how to send ID of product in request?

I want to rate product, but when using postman its working but when hitting request on frontend by axios error showing that id is unefined which I am sending by request.params.

 const { comment, rating } = req.body;
    console.log(rating);
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(id);
    // find product
    const product = await productModel.findById(id);

This is  backend code in which id is getting by request.params and router URL is
router.put("/:id/review", requireSignIn, userRatings);


const submitHandler = async (e, id) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/dp/${id}/review`, {
        comment,
        rating,
      });
      
      console.log(data.message);
      toast.success(data.message);
      setComment("");
      setRating(0);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


<form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <div>
                  <h2>Write a customer review</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="rating">Rating</label>
                  <select
                    id="rating"
                    value={rating}
                    onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                  >
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">1- Bad</option>
                    <option value="2">2- Fair</option>
                    <option value="3">3- Good</option>
                    <option value="4">4- Very good</option>
                    <option value="5">5- Excelent</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="comment">Comment</label>
                  <textarea
                    id="comment"
                    value={comment}
                    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>

                <div>
                  <label />
                  <button className="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>


This is the front end function on SUBMIT FORM. In this function when seing on consol showing id UNDEFINED ?
data: "Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/dp/undefined/review from localhost:3000
In that case I am using PUT method to rate product.


Where is submit handler used? You need to get the elements of the form fields

Kindly see the code of form in which I added on Click to submitHandler .....

That id parameter/value has to come from somewhere, but not the event handler function

Yes it is coming form request.params but showing UNDEFINED ?

No in your browser code

You can archive this by following two ways:

You need to add input tag with type attribute hidden & set it value with product value, after that you can get product id from it.



const App = () => {
  const [rating, setRating] = React.useState(1);
  const [comment, setComment] = React.useState("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Id : ${event.target.id.value}, Rating : ${rating}, Comment : ${comment}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form method="post" className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <h2>Write a customer review</h2>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="5" />

        <div className="form-group mt-2">
          <label htmlFor="rating">Rating</label>
          <select
            className="form-control"
            id="rating"
            name="rating"
            value={rating}
            onChange={(event) => setRating(event.target.value)}
          >
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group mt-2">
          <label htmlFor="comment">Comment</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            id="comment"
            name="comment"
            rows="3"
            value={comment}
            onChange={(event) => setComment(event.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-2">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




You can pass product id to your component using props & get value from it.



const App = ({ id }) => {
  const [rating, setRating] = React.useState(1);
  const [comment, setComment] = React.useState("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Id : ${id}, Rating : ${rating}, Comment : ${comment}`);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form method="post" className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <h2>Write a customer review</h2>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group mt-2">
          <label htmlFor="rating">Rating</label>
          <select
            className="form-control"
            id="rating"
            name="rating"
            value={rating}
            onChange={(event) => setRating(event.target.value)}
          >
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group mt-2">
          <label htmlFor="comment">Comment</label>
          <textarea
            className="form-control"
            id="comment"
            name="comment"
            rows="3"
            value={comment}
            onChange={(event) => setComment(event.target.value)}
          ></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-2">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App id={1005} />, document.getElementById("root"));
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



